# Is it possible call procedure in Scheduled Queries on Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I´m trying call procedures in Scheduled Queries on Bigquery. Unfortunately, occurs the following error: Procedure is not found.

I've tried to call the procedure in several possible ways:

```
CALL project.schema.procedure()
CALL schema.procedure()
CALL procedure()
```

The first two options above work normally through the "compose new query" function.

Thanks for help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem in my case was that the dataset containing the stored procedure was located in the EU region but the scheduled query was by default created in the US region.
I resolved this by creating a new scheduled query and explicitly selecting the EU region in the query settings.